# wp_head inserts og meta tags. where's causing them?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.groundguitar.com/wp-    includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.groundguitar.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
</head>
```

These are lines added by wp_head();. For some reason it adds og tags, and I can't figure out why.
I'm using the Yoast SEO plugin, but have previously used All In One SEO, and they both had og tags disabled, yet this still appeared in the header. Rest of the plugins I'm using are: Facebook Comments by Fat Panda, Contact Form 7 and Any Mobile Theme Switcher. Disabling any of them didn't remove the tags.

Could this be a leftover from a plugin used in the past, which didn't uninstall correctly, and how can I remove it, or at least find out what's causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That definitely looks like something a plugin would add.

First thing I would do is check the header.php file of your theme just to make sure they are not hard coded in there, never hurts to eliminate the obvious first.

Next, do you have JetPack enabled?  If so do you have it's Social Links module enabled?  Those og tags might be generated from there.

Last but not least if they still are showing up you will need to turn of EVERY plugin and check, might be something that another, not so obvious plugin might be doing.

Good luck!

Comment: yup, turns out to be the facebook panda comments plugin. i guess it didn't deactivate correctly when i first tried it. thanks.

Comment: Phew glad you found it.  Sometimes a plugin conflict can be like hunting for a needle in a hay stack.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Yoast plugin provides Opengraph for Facebook and Twitter so that if someone shares your post/page, the desired image with custom title can forward to those social media. You can check https: //www.facebook.com/kumarsn11/posts/747660215383716 this link which redirects user to your website. Its always helpful. Read some basic info about opengraph, you will get basic idea what you are actually using. Read This https: //blog.kissmetrics.com/open-graph-meta-tags/

You can disable it by SEO-> Social-> Add Opengraph Metadata. Disable This.

but I will recommend you not to disable, but use it properly with more customization.

[image]

When you click this social icon, you can use custom title other than original or keep the same for Facebook and Twitter.